# Usage of COALESCE

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have a query making use of `COALESCE()` to count the combination of 2 columns:

```
SELECT method, main_ingredient, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM  `recipes` 
GROUP BY COALESCE( method, main_ingredient )
```

The result is useful. Sample result:

```
method    main_ingredient    cnt
================================
     1    4                  10
     2    1                  6
     3    6                  3
     4    6                  5
     5    2                  4
     6    8                  2
```

However, how can I obtain the results that has `COUNT(*)` equals to 0 ?

UPDATE with expected output:

```
method    main_ingredient    cnt
================================
     1    2                  0
     1    3                  0
     1    5                  0
     1    6                  0
     2    2                  0
     2    3                  0
                .
                .
                .
                .
               etc
```

**UPDATE** added the `tbl_methods` and `tbl_main_ingredients`:

Schema of `tbl_methods`:

```
id    method_name
=================
1     Method 1
2     Method 2
      .
      .
      .
6     Method 6
```

Schema of `tbl_main_ingredients`:

```
id     ingredient_name
======================
1      Ingredient 1
2      Ingredient 2
       .
       .
       .
8      Ingredient 8
```

Both `id` are the primary key of their table, auto-increment.

Comment: Is there any chance that `method` could be `NULL`?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Are you saying you want a list of every combination of method and main_ingredient for which you don't have a recipe?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, exactly what I want.

Comment: @1000111 Both columns are integer and are `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Then I would say the wrong use of `COALESCE`. Better add some sample input and expected output in order to make your requirement lucid.

Comment: @1000111 Added expected output. For sample input, it's just millions of records containing method from `1 - 6` and main_ingredient from `1 - 8`

Comment: Do the `method` and `main_ingredient` ids in your expected result exist in `recipes` table? If they do then why are you expecting the count to be zero for them?

Comment: @1000111 if `COALESCE()` is not the function I should use, what will be the best way to find out the combination with zero counts?

Comment: May be you are not explaining well. So far I guess you want result for each combination of `method` and `main_ingredient` whether they exist in  table `recipes` or not. If they exist then show the corresponding count otherwise show zero for them. If this is your requirement then I need to know in which table all the `method` and `main_ingredient` ids exist?

Comment: @1000111 Agreed that you have to know the possible IDs of `methods` and `main_ingredients`. Indeed `tbl_methods` and `tbl_main_ingredients` exist, which list out there are 1 - 6 for methods and 1 - 8 for main_ingredients

Comment: I think we can come to a solution if you post the structure of those two (`tbl_methods & tbl_main_ingredientes`). @Raptor

Comment: @1000111 added the schema in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make a `CROSS JOIN` between `tbl_methods` and `tbl_main_ingredients` table in order to obtain the all possible combination of method and ingredient.

Later make a left join between the above cross joined table and your `reipes` table on matching `method` and `main_ingredient`.

Thus you will obtain a result for all possible combination of `method` and `main_ingredient`. If any combination exists in `recipes` table then you will get the corresponding count otherwise you will obtain `0` as count.

```
SELECT 
method_ingredients.method_id,
method_ingredients.ingredients_id,
COUNT(R.method) AS cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    TM.id AS method_id,
    TMI.id AS ingredients_id
    FROM tbl_methods TM
    CROSS JOIN tbl_main_ingredients TMI
) AS method_ingredients
LEFT JOIN `recipes` R ON R.method = method_ingredients.method_id AND R.main_ingredient = method_ingredients.ingredients_id
GROUP BY method_ingredients.method_id, method_ingredients.ingredients_id
ORDER BY method_ingredients.method_id, method_ingredients.ingredients_id;
```

**Or**

you can prefer the shorter version of this query:

```
SELECT 
 TM.id AS method_id,
 TMI.id AS ingredients_id,
 COUNT(R.method) AS cnt
FROM tbl_methods TM
CROSS JOIN tbl_main_ingredients TMI
LEFT JOIN `recipes` R ON R.method = TM.id AND R.main_ingredient = TMI.id
GROUP BY TM.id, TMI.id
ORDER BY TM.id, TMI.id;
```

**More:**

**Some subtleties regarding `COUNT`:**

```
SELECT COUNT(0);   Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(-1);  Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(NULL); Result: 0

SELECT COUNT(71); Result: 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68544/0)

**BTW** there's nothing to do with `COALESCE` in your use case. `COALESCE` returns the first `non-NULL` element from the list if there's any otherwise `NULL`.

**Example:**

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL,'abc',NULL,'def'); returns abc

SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);  returns NULL
```

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need to check if the main_ingredient is null

```
SELECT method, ifnull(main_ingredient,0), COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM  `recipes` 
GROUP BY  method
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross join your 2 base tables, then left join on `recipes`. Then, if you count any of the left joined columns, you will get the desired result:

```
select m.id, i.id, count(r.method) as cnt
  from tbl_methods m
 cross join tbl_main_ingredients i
  left join recipes r
    on r.method = m.id
   and r.main_ingredient = i.id
 group by m.id, i.id
 order by m.id, i.id
```